# what is Review object in facebook graph API & how do I post it

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl

I have implemented some of the facebook features using curl and facebook graph APIs as mentioned in the developer website. I am able to post and upload photos.
During the course of adding other features, I came acroos REVIEW object of this graph API.
The page that talks about is: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Review/
Can I please know, what is the REVIEW means and for what it is?

The example they have given redirects to http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=2345053339/reviews. Can I know the exact syntax or parameters to which I can use review.

I want to implement something like where USER is able to post RATING parameter, in int values.

Comment: I think you can't do it, as answer at http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11445839/how-do-i-get-users-to-review-my-app

Comment: Ok, in that case can I upload a message/status with my CUSTOM VARIABLE. I mean, e.g. I reuse post message API from facebook and add some custom field to be uploaded such as RATING(having int values between 1 to 5)

Comment: Customize parameter name is impossible. You may try to put these "Rating = 5" inside "message=" parameter.

Comment: But, in one document page from facebook http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/explicit-sharing/ I am able to see some thing like  curl -X POST https://graph.facebook.com/me/nyccookbook:cook \
     -F "access_token=<valid access_token>"  \
     -F "recipe=http://www.sugarmedia.com/nyccookbook/cookie.html" \
     -F "fb:explicitly_shared=true"; how does the above post works; is this only valid for OPEN GRAPH and not with graph apis? I want exactly something like above but instead of recipe - rating

Comment: I'm not familliar with open graph API, however https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-object-types/ should give you idea how to add new action property.